# Pre tag to show html content from database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pre

I am developing MVC application where I need to show some html content like image , hyperlink , bold , underline text , etc.

I save this content in SQL server database and fetch it from there.

But when I render it as @Model.Description it shows the text instead of html image or bold text.

But when I manually write such html content in pre tag, it is displayed well and good.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you just looking for this?:  `@Html.Raw(Model.Description)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just write razor syntax like `@Model.SomeProperty` it will automatically encode it. So html will be encoded this way and output will containt &gt etc... If you want to inject html you should use `@Raw(Model.Property)` but you need to be aware that this could inject some malicious js...

Comment: thanks @Nemanja todorovic .. This was just what I was looking for. .